# How to get remote pg_dump version?

Tags: postgresql, version, psql, remote-server, pg-dump

When calling pg_dump to backup my database on remote server

```
pg_dump "postgresql://$DB_USER:$DB_PASS@$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT/$DB_NAME" | gzip > $BACKUP_GZ
```

I got below error

> pg_dump: server version: 11.5 (Debian 11.5-3.pgdg90+1); pg_dump version: 10.14 (Ubuntu 10.14-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
> pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch

Currently, I have to try-and-get as [coded here](https://github.com/namgivu/postgres-start/blob/master/backup-db/00aVERBOSE.get_remote_pgdump_version.sh#L7) to detect when pg_dump failed with the mismatch version and get the remote version there - which is a very tiring process.

So my question is what is fastest way to get that remote pg_dump version on remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can simply just go for postgres version cause pg_dump/psql shares same version with postgres version

```
psql "postgresql://$DB_USER:$DB_PASS@$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT" -c 'select version()' -tA
```